# Uncaught ReferenceError: ui is not defined for UI.Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I added "ui.bootstrap" for my application to use ToolTips. After adding "ui.bootstrap", my application is not loading. I think im missing something but not sure, what and how i can fix this?

Can anyone please help?

Thanks,
Sangamesh

P.S. I use angular for my app.

Comment: Did you add the ui-bootstrap script? Something like: <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.10.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script> somewhere in your html after angular is added.

Comment: Please checkout your versions and please read above comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should add '' to ui.bootstrap like this:

```
angular.module('myapp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

bad example:

```
angular.module('myapp', [ui.bootstrap]);
```

hope this helps.